# If it is possible, should images posted as part of questions or answers be cropped down to their essentials?

Tags: discussion

See this question as an example: [USB drive install of Ubuntu 12.04 Server fails - can't find components from CD-ROM](https://askubuntu.com/q/127398/25656).

In my opinion, the relevant parts of both images in the question are about a quarter of the whole images. Does "editing" extend to suitably cropping images? Or is it a bad idea?

Comment: Exactly what I felt when I stumbled upon that question.

Comment: you could do that if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually agree with cropping images, especially in answers.

In this case, Since it is a question, and the pictures are from a camera, they only help as a visual reference, what things look like when it fails, the first picture is well explained, but I think the second picture the text should be copied into the question.

So if the information is copied over we don't really need the pictures much, but I would leave a bit of the background color in the crop if you do end up cropping.

Comment: "I would leave a bit of the background color in the crop if you do end up cropping." Yes, that would retain the context.

Answer (score 5):

Is it really necessary? Then do it. Editing is part of this community's daily work, if you think its worth it then do it.

*It can always be reverted or improved ™*